# Issue with ConnectorConfig

Tags: java, login-errors

I'm using Java to connect to SFDC.  Very simple, generic code:

```
 import com.sforce.soap.partner.Connector;
 import com.sforce.soap.partner.DeleteResult;
 import com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection;
 import com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult;
 import com.sforce.soap.partner.SaveResult;
 import com.sforce.soap.partner.Error;
 import com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject;
 import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
 import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;

import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

 public class LoginTest {

  static String USERNAME ;
  static String PASSWORD ;
  static PartnerConnection connection;

 public static void main(String[] args) {

   ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
   config.setUsername(args[0]);
   config.setPassword(args[1]);
if (args[2].equals("S")) {
config.setAuthEndpoint("https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0") ;
 }
    config.setTraceMessage(true);

  try {

     connection = Connector.newConnection(config);

     // display some current settings
      System.out.println("Auth EndPoint: "+config.getAuthEndpoint());
      System.out.println("Service EndPoint: "+config.getServiceEndpoint());
      System.out.println("Username: "+config.getUsername());
      System.out.println("SessionId: "+config.getSessionId());

      } catch (Exception e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
       }  

     }

   }
```

Now if I enter an invalid password, I get an INVALID_LOGIN exception immediately.  But when an invalid username is entered, it takes 2 - 3 minutes to get the exception.  Any ideas?

Comment: looks logical to me as salesforce in back end would have to look for all the usernames so far created .

Comment: I've seen this hang before, never really get to the bottom of it, though i suspected it was some kind of conflict in project setup, are you defining the classpath yourself or using a pom.xml file?